# Differences between "for ever" and "forever"

Tags: difference

> What are the differences between "***forever***" and "***for ever***" in the
>   meaning and usages?

Answer (score 6):

Both mean the same. When something is [for ever](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forever?q=for%20ever), it's for all time in the future.

In AmE, it's a one word version. However, there's a very little difference. The one-word version refers persistency whereas the two-word term means eternally (though except in the US).

Good information [here](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/02/forever.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are synonymous, however *forever* is far more common (at least in the US) than *for ever*.  I don't think I've ever seen it written as two words and I read quite a lot.

Answer (score -1):

for ever - always
forever- continually,eternal

Answer (score -1):

Forever is a measurement of time. And for ever is beyond time.

Comment: If you would like to discuss the bible, I encourage you to visit [christianity.se].